# change stock availability programmatically

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, products-management, stock

How I can change stock availability ie `in stock` and `out of stock` of product programmatically using product ID?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, you really need to work at your accept ratio.

Comment: for going through your answers and accepting those which were answered correctly :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code should work for you

```
$stock_item = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product_id);
if (!$stock_item->getId()) {
    $stock_item->setData('product_id', $product_id);
    $stock_item->setData('stock_id', 1); 
}

$stock_item->setData('is_in_stock', 1); // is 0 or 1
$stock_item->setData('manage_stock', 1); // should be 1 to make something out of stock

try {
    $stock_item->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "{$e}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone marked this as duplicate, it is not. Those looking to do it through database can refer to original answer of Shoaib Munir - [Magento 2 - Bulk update stock programmatically - Using database query](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285524/magento-2-bulk-update-stock-programmatically-using-database-query/285534#285534)

Apart from two updates in cataloginventory_stock_item and cataloginventory_stock_status; also update inventory_source_item. Your cron should reindex automatically after that