# Debug/Disable automatic set out of stock when lower qty reached

Tags: stock

Magento Automatically set a product when a certain qty limit is reached:
`system -> configuration -> catalog -> inventory -> Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock`

As pointed out by @pitmeister,`Allow qty Below 0` should disable this behavior.

The problem is:

- I already have `Allow qty Below 0` (frontend/backend works as expected so status is not changed)
- BUT: I'm importing stock information using a third party extension and the import action set product `out of stock` in case the qty imported is 0.

How can I debug this ? Where is the code that change product stock status to out of stock because of the Qty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check for the qty is performed by `verifyStock()` and on the base of its output the status is set by `_beforeSave()` method:

- `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::_beforeSave()`
- `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::verifyStock($qty = null)`

In case you need to perform some programmatically stock changes, here there is a possible approach:
[change stock availability programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6123/change-stock-availability-programmatically)

Answer (score 5):

If you allow backorders (Allow qty Below 0), the setting 'Stock Availability' will not be set to Out of Stock once the product reaches qty = 0

Comment: Thanks, do you have idea where is the code related to it ?

Comment: Take a look at `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock::updateSetOutOfStock`

Comment: that method is called when you change the configuration setting `Allow qty Below 0`. 
I think it is meant to update the stock for the full catalog ... so it is not what I'm looking for