# Magento 2 - Bulk update stock programmatically - Using database query

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, cron, stock

I have 10 products; 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
I want to be able to bulk change 1, 3, 4, 5 and 9 to 0 quantity and out of stock and 2, 6, 7, 8 and 10 to 100 quantity and in stock.
How can I do this programmatically?
I have and am running magento 2.3.

Comment: @joeybab3 incorrect this is for M2

Comment: This is not duplicate, because other question is not for magento 2

Answer (score 0):

use this script it will help you out.

First Initialize required instances
You can use object manager if you are using custom script (But it is not recommended)

```
protected $productRepository;
protected $stockRegistry;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    ...
)
{
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
}
```

Now use above instances and do update stock like this:

```
    $outOfStockProducts = array(1, 3, 4, 5, 9);
    $inStockProducts = array(2, 6, 7, 8, 10);

    //For out of stock products
    foreach($outOfStockProducts as $k=>$id){
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($id);
        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($product->getSku());
        $stockItem->setQty(0);
        $this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($product->getSku(), $stockItem);
    }

    //For 100 stock products
    foreach($inStockProducts as $k=>$id){
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($id);
        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($product->getSku());
        $stockItem->setQty(100);
        $this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($product->getSku(), $stockItem);
    }
```

## Edit:

If you want to do it with object manager (Which is not recommended) then use this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$stockRegistry = $objectManager->create('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

    $outOfStockProducts = array(1, 3, 4, 5, 9);
    $inStockProducts = array(2, 6, 7, 8, 10);

    //For out of stock products
    foreach($outOfStockProducts as $k=>$id){
        $product = $productRepository->getById($id);
        $stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($product->getSku());
        $stockItem->setQty(0);
        $stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($product->getSku(), $stockItem);
    }

    //For 100 stock products
    foreach($inStockProducts as $k=>$id){
        $product = $productRepository->getById($id);
        $stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($product->getSku());
        $stockItem->setQty(100);
        $stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($product->getSku(), $stockItem);
    }
```

## Edit 2

You need these commands to update stock directly on databae

```
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item set qty=100 where product_id IN(2, 6, 7, 8, 10);
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_status SET qty=100 AND stock_status=1 WHERE product_id IN(2, 6, 7, 8, 10);


UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item set qty=0 where product_id IN(2, 6, 7, 8, 10);
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_status SET qty=0 AND stock_status=0 WHERE product_id IN(2, 6, 7, 8, 10);
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi Shoaib, I need this in a custom script (object manager)

Comment: answer updated, please check

Comment: Hi Shoaib, that's perfect. Now all I need is to do them all in bulk, i.e. something like "UPDATE product_stock_table SET qty=0, in_stock=0 WHERE id IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 9)"

Comment: The statement above can do ~10,000 in under 0.025 seconds, but the PDO in your example takes over 2 minutes just to do ~500, that is what I am referring to.

Comment: It is not recommended to do direct update command. The solution that I have gave you is the best solution I can give. Now it's up to you how you can apply it

Comment: Shoaib, I need to do it direct, otherwise the database will take too long to write!

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?